# Adobe Javascript: escaping backslashes and quotation marks

Tags: javascript, adobe-javascript

I'm trying to populate a field with a simple script:

```
var a =""
if (this.getField("Check Box7").value == "Yes")
{
a='""\\\\server\\\share\\\""'
}
```

which yields this result: `"\\server\share\"`
I need this result:        \\server\share  (so no quotation marks)

How can I obtain this result?

Comment: `trimmedA = a.substring(1, a.length-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This input will give the required output, as specified in the initial question:

```
var a =""
if (this.getField("Check Box7").value == "Yes")
{
a="\\\\server\\\share\\";
}
```